# Convolutional NN binary classifier makes predictions between 0.3 and 1, expected 0-1

Tags: conv-neural-network, accuracy, keras, cross-entropy, dropout

I'm training a multiple input model for binary classification using Conv2D for one of the branches, and the results are very good on the validation set. I am using Dropout of 0.5 just before the output layer: that would explain the better accuracy on the validation set.

Settings are:

```
mm2.compile(optimizer='adam',
                       loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                       metrics=['accuracy'])
```

A few things are strange in terms of the results it is giving:

1. Sometimes I have to restart the training and reset Keras backend to get it to learn something, or it will remain going through epochs with the same exact values.
2. I can train for hundreds of epochs and accuracy remains at its best value. In my experience even using dropout, performance decreases if you train for too long.
3. Loss reaches its best value of about 0.3 and remains there, and that seems to be the reason why all the predictions made by the model are between 0.3 and 1.0, as shown by the histogram (made from the output of the model's method predict).

The behaviour I would expect would be a histogram with two clear peaks close to 0 and 1, instead of 0.3 and 1.0, and few values in between.

The only explanation I have been able to find online is that I would need a bigger training set, which makes sense.

I would like to know if there could be some other obvious explanation or obvious mistake that I'm making in order to obtain these results.

[image: TRAINING HISTORY]

Predictions made on Validation data `(mm2.predict(X_val))`: Please note x-axis ranges from 0.3 to 1.0
[image: RESULTS]

Comment: When you say that all loss values are between 0.3 and 1.0, what do you mean? Do you mean that the binary cross entropy value for all samples is between 0.3 and 1.0 in a certain epoch? Or do you mean that the average binary cross entropy loss value in a certain *set of multiple epochs* is between 0.3 and 1.0? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I say that **binary cross-entropy loss** does not go below 0.3. That could be what is making the **predictions** range from 0.3 and 1, not from 0 to 1 as I would expect.

Comment: Please re-read my comment. What you've written is not responsive to my question.

Comment: I am clarifying, because you begin your comment with "When you say that all loss values are between 0.3 and 1.0". But I never say that. I will try to edit the question so that it is clearer.

Comment: What does "all my results are between 0.3 and 1.0" mean?

Comment: Oh, I mean the predictions made by the model. "results" is not the right word, I will change that.

Comment: What does the histogram show? It's not labelled. It's not clear what data the histogram is presenting.

Comment: Sorry, it is explained now: the histogram is made from the output of the predict method  called on the model. Note the x axis starts from 0.3, not 0. Training labels are all 0 or 1.

Comment: Does this pattern persist when you don't use dropout?

Comment: No, loss goes to 0.1 without dropout, but without dropout, training accuracy and loss are both better than validations, which I'm trying very hard to avoid.